# What is the best way to calculate overtime in my rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime

Hi I am building a small rails meetings application for myself. I have a table called Meetings with 5 columns
`name:string start_date:datime end_date:datetime duration:integer overtime:integer`

My Question is if there is a better way of calculating overtime than what i am doing ?

Duration is total time between start_date and end_date per day there can be multiple meetings per day.

Overtime is total duration per day minus 7 hours 25 minutes (26700 seconds) any total meeting duration over 7.25 per day is overtime.
I am getting my desired result (see image below) but I am wondering if there is a better way? I am using an if statement in my index.html.erb. to get my desired result as the overtime data getting saved to the database is not the actual overtime data i need.

From the image below i typically want only the "22 minutes and 40 minutes" to be saved as and integer. I will also  want to show the total overtime per week which is why i dont think my way will work. Is their a better way?

Thanks in advance on any inputs.

The two calculated columns in my Meeting.rb model file duration and overtime

```
class Meeting < ApplicationRecord

#callbacks save to db

 before_save :set_duration
  before_save :daily_total_ot

#calculate duration

 def set_duration
      self.duration = (end_date - start_date).to_i
    end

#Calculate total duration for each day 

def daily_total_duration
     
      Meeting.where("start_date >= ? AND end_date < ?", self.start_date.beginning_of_day, self.start_date.end_of_day).sum(:duration) 
      
 end

#calculate total overtime for each day 

  def daily_total_ot
     self.overtime = Meeting.where("start_date >= ? AND end_date < ?", self.start_date.beginning_of_day, self.start_date.end_of_day).sum(:duration) - 26700.to_i
    
      end

end
```

in my view meetings .index.html.erb i have

```
<h1>Meetings</h1><%= Time.zone.now.strftime('%d-%b-%Y')  %>
<table class="table">
  <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>End date</th>
      <th>Duration</th>
      <th>Duration Time</th>
      <th>Daily Total <br>Duration</th>
      <th>overtime saved</th>
      <th>Real OT</th>
      <th>Show</th>
      <th>Edit</th>
      <th>Destroy</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @meetings.each do |meeting| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= meeting.name %></td>
        <td><%= meeting.start_date.strftime("%d-%b-%Y %I:%M %p") %></td> 
        <td><%= meeting.end_date.strftime("%d-%b-%Y %I:%M %p") %></td>

        <td><%= meeting.duration %></td>
        
        <td><%= Time.at(meeting.daily_total_duration).utc.strftime("%H hours and %M minutes ") %></td>
       <td><%= meeting.daily_total_ot %></td>

       <% if  (meeting.daily_total_duration) > 26700 %>
        <td><%= Time.at(meeting.daily_total_ot).utc.strftime("%H hours and %M minutes ") %></td>
         <% else  %>
        <td>No Overtime</td>
        <% end %>
       
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', meeting %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_meeting_path(meeting) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', meeting, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
        
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br><br>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the current approach, you cannot "save" any meeting again or it will get the wrong calculation.

The "correct" query for overtime is

```rb
def previous_meetings_for_same_day
  # meeting should start today ...
  start = start_date.beginning_of_day
  # ...and finish before this one
  limit = end_date - 1.second
  
  # notice the use of open ranges instead of raw SQL
  Meeting.where(start_date: start.., end_date: ..limit)
end

def daily_total_duration
  previous_meetings_for_same_day.sum(:duration).to_i + duration
end

def computed_overtime
  # clamp "forces" a value to fit in the given range
  # in this case if the receiver is negative, it returns 0
  (daily_total_duration - 26700).clamp(0..)
end

def daily_total_ot
  self.overtime = computed_overtime
end
```

This way, earlier meetings are taken into account for later meetings and not the other way around.

By clamping the difference, you also avoid saving negative values.

---

UPDATE:

If you use PostgreSQL, you can use the "interval" type, which maps to `ActiveSupport::Duration` in ruby.

With that, the methods change a bit, because they are not integers anymore:

```rb
MAX_DAILY_DURATION = 7.hours + 25.minutes

def set_duration
  self.duration = end_date - start_date
end

def daily_total_duration
  previous_meetings_for_same_day.sum(:duration) + duration
end

def computed_overtime
  # clamp "forces" a value to fit in the given range
  # in this case if the receiver is negative, it returns 0
  (daily_total_duration - MAX_DAILY_DURATION).clamp(0.seconds..)
end

def daily_total_ot
  self.overtime = computed_overtime
end
```

Comment: thanks for your answer you have given be a lot to think about should you add .to_i to the end of the the daily_total_duration method?  i can mark your answer as correct then

Comment: Duration should already be an integer. What part of the method does not give you an integer result?

Comment: sorry my mistake i left out my own method for duration

Comment: Updated, although I cannot see a case where it would not be an integer